# Send request to REST API NOT via browser

Tags: javascript, rest, request

I'd like to write a script to make REST API requests to some address. The problem is, that the address might not be accessable by everyone and also uses a token for authorization, which I wouldn't like to give away.
So, my idea is to make a request to this API, trigger is a button within a webpage, but the request itself should be sent from the server itself, who's hosting the webpage, but I don't know if this is makeable.

I already wrote a sample script, which creates a request from within the browser. It works, but only for those clients, which have access granted to the server via firewall.

Expected result is that the webpage is showing from results when the script is executed.

Comment: One option is to set up nginx to attach the authorisation header and pass it on to the other API.

Comment: The other would be to just have your own API server to be receiving the request and then making the request. In any case are going to need to set up your own server, which isn't too hard.

Comment: Make the button trigger an ajax request to run a script server side which makes the request for the user and reveals nothing on the page itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your clientside code should make a request to your server, which will then make a request to the API by passing the credentials, and return the response back to the client. Through that your credentials stay on the server and are not exposed.

```
 Client <- request -> your Server <- request + credentials -> API
```

Comment: Ok, sounds to me like using a server side script as proxy gate which executes the action sent from the client javascript code.
Are there any well known resources or examples on how to build such a construct?